# Generic lists in scala

Tags: scala, generics

As I was working with Java I was able to create generic lists with constraints, covariant, Contravariant etc..

`List<? extends Chat> chats=new ArrayList<Siamois>();` ...

But know I have to work in Scala I used constraints for methods and for class for instance :

```
def addToList[T <: Chat](t:T):List[T]=List[T](t)
```

but in fact is there a way to write these lines of java in Scala ?

```
 List<? extends Chat> chats=new ArrayList<Siamois>();
List<? super Siamois> siamois2=new ArrayList<Chat>();
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The literal translation would be

```
import java.util.{List, ArrayList}

val chats: List[_ <: Chat] = new ArrayList[Siamois]
val siamois2: List[_ >: Siamois] = new ArrayList[Chat]
```

But note that the immutable `List` from the Scala standard library is covariant by definition. In idiomatic Scala code you won't need use-site variance. You'll probably want to read up on Scala's declaration-site variance.